# Why forwarding unit in MIPS processor does not store always data from WB stage to ID stage?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, cpu-hazard

Hey to everyone I am trying to understand 5 stage pipeline MIPS with forwarding unit
So I found a problem which has raw data hazards
The problem is the following :

```
Ι1 and $1, $1, $2
Ι2 add $2, $1, $2
Ι3 lw  $2, –20($3)
Ι4 sub $4, $2, $4
```

Dependencies : (Ι1, Ι2, $1) ,  (Ι3, Ι4, $2)

the pipeline with hazards is the following :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3LiU.jpg)

The solution of the forwarding unit is :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jONmf.jpg)

But I could not understand why forwarding unit store data from (EX to EX , WB to EX) And not to WB to ID for these two dependencies
Also why we have to use a NOP instruction between I3 and I4 instruction

My solution is the following :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMzjC.jpg)

Comment: EX->EX allows the next instruction to use the result the next cycle.  Waiting for WB->ID would take multiple extra cycles.  You *can* design a CPU that stalls instead of forwards, but it's a performance disaster for chains of computations on the same value.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline#Data_hazards

Comment: There is no hazard between I3 and I4 that are shown.  Check your register numbers.  Either there is a typo in the code or the analysis is wrong.

Comment: You should add timings: simple cycle number to your diagrams.  It those diagrams, time moves forward by column, so put cycle numbers at the top of each column.  A later column is in a later cycle and later in time (while earlier column in earlier cycle and earlier in time).  It is impossible for a later column to forward its result to an earlier column to use a source since that would require time travel. which hasn't been discovered as yet.  Forwarding arrows in a diagram laid out like that need to go forwards with time (or at least not go backward).

Comment: If you really think forwarding backwards in time is the only solution, then that means you have to stall the instruction receiving the forward until its receiving stage is 1 past the stage sending the forward. so that the forward now works "forward" in time.

Comment: Forwarding arrows should appear to go forward in time.  The only exception is WB and ID, which, in most coursework, are allowed to overlap, having the effect of ID being capable reading the result that WB is writing in the same cycle.  The reason this works is b/c the WB is very fast as it doesn't have to compute a value (it is given the value by MEM) -- all the other stages have to compute an output value so that isn't ready until the end of the cycle.  Usually we wouldn't even consider WB->ID as a forward, but more the first point where a forward isn't actually needed (YMMV though).

Comment: If you want further help with this you'll have to make corrections to the errors.

Comment: @ErikEidt So I has to use stall **( - )** instead of arrows?

Comment: The load-to-use there is only one instruction apart, so it will need both a forward and a stall.  Without the forward (MEM->EX) I4 would have to stall until I4's ID stage lines up with I3's WB stage, which would cost more cycles.  With the forward, I4's EX stage needs to stall until it is *after* I3's MEM stage, since it is the MEM stage that produces the `lw` result, the forward to use there is MEM->EX, which will take one cycle of stall, and then the forward mitigates other stalls.

Comment: Let's also note that this code sequence is nonsensical, in that I2 target's $2, but so does I3, without consuming $2.  So, there is wasteful effort to generate an unused $2 value, which is usually not the case in textbook examples.  I'd check your code sequence and registers again.